# Symfony 2 classnotfoundexception

Tags: php, class, symfony

I have ran into a problem with symfony 2. Everything worked fine till a certain point.

I have a simple controller action, a entity class, and a form (abstract type) class. I am getting the issue:

> ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "Enquiry" from namespace "Symfony\Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity" in /var/www/dellf2/src/Blogger/BlogBundle/Controller/PageController.php line 26. Do you need to "use" it from another namespace?

I have checked the Enquiry.php and it sits at the right place (Blogger/BlogBundle/Entity/Enquiry.php). I checked permissions and it looks fine(755). Even if I try including the file with include_once(), it isn't working.

Enquiry.php

```
// src/Blogger/BlogBundle/Entity/Enquiry.php

namespace Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity;

class Enquiry
{

protected $name;
protected $email;
protected $subject;
protected $body;

public function getName()
{
    return $this->name;
}

public function setName($name)
{
    $this->name = $name;
}

public function getEmail()
{
    return $this->email;
}

public function setEmail($email)
{
    $this->email = $email;
}

public function getSubject()
{
    return $this->subject;
}

public function setSubject($subject)
{
    $this->subject = $subject;
}

public function getBody()
{
    return $this->body;
}

public function setBody($body)
{
    $this->body = $body;
}

}

?>
```

PageController.php

```
<?php

// src/Blogger/BlogBundle/Controller/PageController.php

 namespace Blogger\BlogBundle\Controller;
 //include_once('../Entity/Enquiry.php');

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity\Enquiry;
use Symfony\Blogger\BlogBundle\Form\EnquiryType;

  class PageController extends Controller
{
public function indexAction()
{
    return $this->render('BloggerBlogBundle:Page:index.html.twig');
}

public function aboutAction()
{
    return $this->render('BloggerBlogBundle:Page:about.html.twig');
}

public function contactAction()
{
    $enquiry = new Enquiry();
    $form = $this->createForm(new EnquiryType(), $enquiry);

    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if($request->getMethod() == 'POST'){
        $form->bindRequest($request);

        if($form->isValid()){
            //Perform some action, such as sending an email

            //Redirect - This is important to prevent users re-posting the form if they refresh the page
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('BloggerBlogBundle_contact'));
        }
    }
    return $this->render('BloggerBlogBundle:Page:contact.html.twig', array('form'=> $form->createView()));
}
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add

```
use \Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity\Enquiry;
```

under the namespace line.

Maybe autoloader is sarching in wrong place.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. But do i need to add it in PageController.php? I already have it there.

Comment: It seems that your entity is not in Symfony namespace, so just try to remove "Symfony" from both Blogger use clauses.

Comment: Thanks Michal, yeah true said, that was my problem.

Answer (score 3):

In this same example, a similar error was popping up.

```
Attempted to load class "MaxLength" from namespace "Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?
500 Internal Server Error - ClassNotFoundException

       $metadata->addPropertyConstraint('subject', new NotBlank());
 -->   $metadata->addPropertyConstraint('subject', new MaxLength(50));
       $metadata->addPropertyConstraint('body', new MinLength(50));
```

Ends up that the problem was using a depreciated set of classes.

Instead of using:

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\MinLength;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\MaxLength;
```

and

```
$metadata->addPropertyConstraint('subject', new MaxLength(50));
$metadata->addPropertyConstraint('body', new MinLength(50));
```

You should use:

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Length;
```

and

```
$metadata->addPropertyConstraint('subject', new Length(array('max' => 50)));
$metadata->addPropertyConstraint('body', new Length(array('min' => 50)));
```

References:

http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/reference/constraints/Length.html
http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/reference/constraints/MinLength.html

> The MinLength constraint is deprecated since version 2.1 and will be
>   removed in Symfony 2.3. Use Length with the min option instead.